# How to vertically stretch columns with panel inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and I have a row with 3 columns with each of them having a panel

```
    <div class="row clearfix dashboard">
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-opaque">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Schneehöhen</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

The panels have a different height, but I want to have them all with equal height.
I tried using display:flex on row but this affected only the columns to have an equal height, the panels remained the same.
So how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: red">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Schneehöhen</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="panel-body"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: white">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color: blue "></div>
</div>
```

And use this `css` with that

```
.row[class*="col-"] {
margin-bottom: -99999px;
padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
.row {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

or here is another way to do the same with this `css`

```
.row {
display: table;
}

.row [class*="col-"] {
float: none;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Flexbox approach flexbox [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/dqy3ddys/)

```
.row-eq-height {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
}
```

Comment: is there also a flexbox approach?

Comment: @dc10 try adding ` display:flex;` only in `.row`. Thats what you mean right?

Comment: exactly, but it didn't work. since the height just got applied correctly to the col but not to the panel

Comment: @dc10 look at the demo i included. its working fine in there

Comment: @dc10 sorry i could not figure it out as well but i found another solution for you [using span](http://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/1rbduoz2/)

Comment: @dc10 i cant figure out how to solve the problem is but the problem here is with the `panel` height. You need to stretch the panel body to stretch and fit the parent div

Comment: please see my newest answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured out now how to solve it:

```
.row{
display:flex;
}
```

the descending col needs flex as well

```
.row [class*='col-']{
display:flex;
}

.panel{
flex:1
}
```